# Using asciidoc, is it possible to tag a single word as source code instead of an entire line?

Tags: documentation-generation, intellij-plugin, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am currently writing a document describing the project I am working on, using asciidoc plugin for Intellij. Basically, I know that this works :

```
[source, java]
int i = 0;
```

Output will be :

```
int i = 0;
```

with the grey rectangle, as expected, to specify it's a sample code.

But can you, like StackOverlow does, apply this tag to a single word, without newline needed?

Basically, can you have the grey rectangle on a single word without newline needed, like in the following example :

"This value will be stored in `Myobject`" ?

Do not hesitate if it is not clear enough, this question is kind of hard to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline code highlighting is possible by enclosing your text / words in single or double backticks:

```
This value will be stored in `Myobject`.
This value will be stored in ``Myobject``.
```

**Result:**

> This value will be stored in `Myobject`.

See also the docs: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#source-code

Comment: Thanks Mike! Working like a charm